# Is there an alternative to HTTPS for securing a web site?

Tags: wcf, web-services, web-applications, https

At work we are always having numerous problems with our x.509 certificates that we use for https and I was wondering is there a useful alternative for securing the communication between a server and the browser.

---

**Edit** 
Could also be that we are using IIS x.509 and WCF

Comment: Agree with @Dustin; but... What numerous problems?

Comment: It's fine so long as it's working but updating the certificate and for development it's a pain.

Answer (score 4):

Force site to only allow local traffic and use VPN to restrict access to local network. Other than that you will need to use HTTPS to force encryption.

Comment: Yeah but that's not really a solution for commercial web apps

Comment: Agree, but that was not specified. What kind of problems with SSL do you have?